# How does Intune know about custom macOS developer certificates

Tags: code-signing, package-management

We (an organization) want to start with (re-)packaging of macOS applications and distribution with Intune. I am aware that I will need to sign a .pkg file with a Developer Certificate for distribution as an LOB-Application.

**Question:**

Do I (or the customer) need to install our developer certificate in Intune such that it knows the certificate for checking the package prior distribution or are all developer certificates of Apple are known to Intune?

PS: If you have any official document which answers this question, I would also appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to know each certificate individually in order to check them. This property comes from what is known as the "chain of trust" when dealing with certificates.

Each Developer Certificate has been signed by Apple using their key. An app signed with a Developer Certificate includes not only the name of the custom developer, but also the chain of trust, so that it is evident whether or not Apple has signed that Developer Certificate.

Thus you only need to know Apple's certificate in order to validate whether an app has been signed by a key that Apple has approved.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I have not thought about it in this way. It makes sense.